# MongoDb via jndi

Tags: java, mongodb, jndi, nosql

Do you know if it is possible to setup mongodb instance in spring like any other db via datasource from jndi?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean like regular RDBMS with JDBC access, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is possible, why relying in someone elses code when you can create your own JNDI factory? 
just create a class that implements javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory and a bean that pulls mongo from the JNDI context, I configured this for spring data-mongo MongoTemplate object.

```
public class CustomMongoJNDIFactory implements ObjectFactory {

public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx,
        Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws Exception {

    validateProperty(obj, "Invalid JNDI object reference");

    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = null;
    String db = null;
    String host = null;
    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    int port = 27017;

    Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
    Enumeration<RefAddr> props = ref.getAll();
    while (props.hasMoreElements()) {
        RefAddr addr = (RefAddr) props.nextElement();
        String propName = addr.getType();
        String propValue = (String) addr.getContent();
        if (propName.equals("db")) {
            db = propValue;
        } else if (propName.equals("host")) {
            host = propValue;
        } else if (propName.equals("username")) {
            username = propValue;
        } else if (propName.equals("password")) {
            password = propValue;
        } else if (name.equals("port")) {
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(propValue);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new NamingException("Invalid port value " + propValue);
            }
        }

    }

    // validate properties
    validateProperty(db, "Invalid or empty mongo database name");
    validateProperty(host, "Invalid or empty mongo host");
    validateProperty(username, "Invalid or empty mongo username");
    validateProperty(password, "Invalid or empty mongo password");

    //create mongo template
    mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo(host, port), db,
            new UserCredentials(username, password));

    return mongoTemplate;
}


/**
 * Validate internal String properties
 * 
 * @param property
 * @param errorMessage
 * @throws NamingException
 */
private void validateProperty(String property, String errorMessage)
        throws NamingException {
    if (property == null || property.trim().equals("")) {
        throw new NamingException(errorMessage);
    }
}

/**
 * Validate internal Object properties
 * 
 * @param property
 * @param errorMessage
 * @throws NamingException
 */
private void validateProperty(Object property, String errorMessage)
        throws NamingException {
    if (property == null) {
        throw new NamingException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

}

Spring bean:

```
@Configuration
@Qualifier("mongoTemplate")
public class CustomMongoTemplate  {


 public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
     Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
     Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
     return (MongoTemplate) envCtx.lookup("bean/MyMongoBean");
    }
}
```

Context.xml:

```
<Resource name="bean/MyMongoBean" auth="Container"
        type="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
        factory="com.package.CustomMongoJNDIFactory"
        host="" db="" username="" password=""/>
```

Web.xml

```
    <resource-env-ref>
    <description>Mongo JNDI configuration</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>comp/env/bean/MyMongoBean</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Answer (score 3):

Reusing Juan Melo's custom implementation of `ObjectFactory` interface (`CustomMongoJNDIFactory`), it can be also configured using jndi-lookup tag of Spring's `jee` namespace and corresponding Tomcat config in `context.xml file`, like this:

`spring-mongodb-persistence-context.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="mongoTemplate" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jndi/MongoDB" expected-type="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" />

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.package.repository.mongodb" />

</beans>
```

`context.xml`:

```
<Resource name="jndi/MongoDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
    factory="com.package.mongo.CustomMongoJNDIFactory"
    username="test"
    password="test"
    host="localhost"
    port="27017"
    db="test" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you'll need a JDBC driver impl for MongoDB. I have only found one, and it's referred as "experimental" from the MongoDB page: [GitHub JDBC Driver for MongoDB](http://github.com/erh/mongo-jdbc) .

to workaroud this limitation, you could setup some Spring beans and create a MongoDB implementation for your application DAO (this way, you won't need to change the DAO interface and it's client components).

This articles may help:

- [Plain Simple MongoDB Spring
  Integration](http://java.dzone.com/articles/plain-simple-mongodb-spring)
- [Migrating a Spring/Hibernate application to MongoDB](http://drorbr.blogspot.com/2010/02/migrating-springhibernate-application.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is another effort to provide a JDBC driver impl for MongoDB.  Here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mongojdbcdriver

Not complete by any measure, but will hopefully provide a JDBC implementation that is familiar to Java developers soon.