# Placing MongoDB server properties in context.xml

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

In an `JAVA` web project hosted in `Tomcat` with a backend `ORACLE/MYSQL` We could add a `<Resource>` like below (consider connection an `Oracle` Server)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/myProject">

  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
  factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory" 
  maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" 
  maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/TestDB" password="dbPAss" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBHOST:PORT:SERVICENAME" 
  user="dbUser"/>

  <Loader delegate="true"/>
</Context>
```

in the `context.xml` of the project and only changing a few things if its connecting a `MySQL`
and 
can used in a `JAVA SERVLET` by using

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
```

and then creating its `Connection` Object

What should be the correct syntax for using it for `MongoDB`?

I am intending to store the HOST,PORT, USERNAME and PASSWORD for the MongoDB server.

Comment: Does MongoDB have a JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat only supports JDBC DataSources when using `<Resource>` elements (well, it supports other things like SMTP sessions, etc. but for databases, they must be JDBC-based). There is currently no JDBC driver for MongoDB (because it's not a relational database, and the JDBC API makes no sense for it) (unless you want to try this thing: https://github.com/erh/mongo-jdbc), so you'll have to manage your own resource pool for it.

Answer (score 1):

actually there is a JDBC driver for MongoDB.  one was just released by a company called UnityJDBC.  you can download the program and driver for free at...

http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat (or more specifically, JNDI) does in fact support arbitrary resources (`<Resource>` elements in `config.xml`), including connection information for MongoDB without requiring that MongoDB (or any other non-RDBMS) be wrangled to use JDBC.  All that's required is an implementation of the `javax.naming` API to define the properties of your custom resource (see [Adding Custom Resource Factories](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories) in the Tomcat JNDI HOW-TO reference).

I recently found [this GitHub project](https://github.com/pozil/mongodb-jndi-datasource) which aims to store MongoDB datasource connection information as a JNDI resource while using the official MongoDB Java client.

If you're using Spring, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076254/mongodb-via-jndi) provides information for MongoDB datasource configuration via a JNDI resource when using Spring (and that code could also be used as a guide to creating your own custom JNDI resource loader for MongoDB or any other configuration properties you with to store in the Tomcat `context.xml`).