# How to create the Mongo database connection in context.xml in Java web project?

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets, mongodb-java

Although there are many proper tutorials to show how to connect relational database in Java, I really in doubt with the MongoDB mechanism working with Java. Normally people would create a connection in context.xml to interact with a relational database with JSP/servlet to do web project. However, with NoSQL database, I don't quite get any resources on how to perform this connection in a nice constructed way rather than many resources with framework lately and working seamlessly.

If any experts could show me how really highly appreciate it.

Comment: It's [not that simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450437/placing-mongodb-server-properties-in-context-xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample servlet/JSP code with configuration to connect to MongoDB database and view a query results in the JSP page.

**(i) JNDI configuration to access MongoDB database (META-INF/context.xml):**

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="mongodb/mongoClient"
              auth="Container"
              type="com.mongodb.MongoClient"
              closeMethod="close"
              factory="com.mongodb.client.jndi.MongoClientFactory"
              singleton="true"
              connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017" />
</Context>
```

**(ii) WEB-INF/web.xml (include this within the "web-app" tags):**

```
 <resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>mongodb/mongoClient</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>com.mongodb.MongoClient</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**(iii) Servlet class:**

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name="java:comp/env/mongodb/mongoClient")
    private MongoClient client;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        // ---- This works too; can be used instead of the @Resource  ----
        //try {
        //  Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        //  client = (MongoClient) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/mongodb/mongoClient");
        //}
        //catch (NamingException ex) {
        //  throw new ServletException(ex);
        //}

        MongoCollection<Document> coll = client.getDatabase("test")
                                               .getCollection("books");
        
        List<Document> docData = new ArrayList<>();
        coll.find()
             .projection(new Document("title", 1)
                                .append("author", 1)
                                .append("_id", 0))
            .limit(10)
            .into(docData);
        List<String> data = docData.stream()
                                   .map(doc -> doc.get("title") + ", " + doc.get("author"))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
        req.setAttribute("bookdata", data);
    
        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");
        view.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**(iv) view.jsp:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
        <title>Test App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Books List</h3>
    
        <c:forEach items="${bookdata}" var="book">
            ${book}<br>
        </c:forEach>
    ...
```

Comment: prasad_ Is the @Resource(name="java:comp/env/mongodb/mongoClient") refer to the context.xml?

Comment: Yes, thats the JNDI resource. You can also try using the the naming `Context` API (refer to the commented code in the servlet class)..

Comment: Thanks, what about getting user input like getpara in the servlet? You can youtube a tutorial using jsp/servlet as there is no much resource I can find. Always hibernate or mysql.

Comment: User input is to be from a JSP page, not servlet. The input data is to be processed from the servlet. Servlets / JSP allows design and build a MVC (Model View Controller) web application, in which the JSP is the view (of MVC).

Comment: Thank you so much to answer my question. I will post another question about how to build UserDao with MongoDB.