# How configure JBoss for MongoDb via JNDI without Datasource in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss7.x, jndi

Can you please help me out in configuring MongoDB Resource Entries via JNDI with out usage of Data Source in JBOSS AS7.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "MongoDB Resource Entries via JNDI" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076254/mongodb-via-jndi

Comment: please find the above link which is done in tomcat i need to do it in JBoss AS 7 in similar way thanks in advance