# How to connect MongoDB via JNDI in java

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

Currently i am using the following code for connecting into MongoDB via java.

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://10.0.8.78:27017/mydb");          
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

I want to create MongoClient object using JNDI.Following is my jndi configuration in wildfly.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <object-factory name="java:global/MyMongoClient" module="org.mongodb" class="com.mongodb.client.jndi.MongoClientFactory">
            <environment>
                <property name="connectionString" value="mongodb://10.0.8.78:27017/mydb" />
            </environment>
        </object-factory>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming />
</subsystem>
```

What is the code change needed for me to create MongoClient object for connecting into MongoDB via JNDI.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076254/mongodb-via-jndi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke mongodb client using this below code,

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/LocalMongoClient")
private MongoClient mongoClient;
```

or

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
MongoClient mongoClient = (MongoClient) ctx.lookup("java:global/LocalMongoClient")
```

Comment: I used the second method and i am getting the following error."Exception->com.mongodb.MongoClient cannot be cast to com.mongodb.MongoClient". I am using mongo-java-driver-3.4.0.jar in "wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/mongodb/main" directory and "mongodb-driver-3.4.0.jar" in "wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/UPLOADER.war/WEB-INF/lib" directory. can you help me to resolve it.

Comment: You should change lookup name like "java:global/MyMongoClient". Because i mentioned wrong name in the above example.

Comment: The issue was because i was using mongo-java-driver-3.4.0.jar in modules and application lib. Later i removed it from application lib and used jboss-deployment-structure.xml for loading it from modules directory.

Comment: Is it possible to create JNDI connection using JBoss 5.1(Not wildfly) for MongoDB. If yes can you suggest me a link or document. @Ganesan

Comment: The below link will guide you to configure JNDI in Jboss,

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/printer/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/jndi-resources-howto.html

Comment: In pom.xml file, I had to add «org.mongodb» text to <Dependencies> tag in the path /project/build/plugins/plugin/configuration/archive/manifestEntries/Dependencies, to make it works.

Comment: I'm getting this exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'java:global/MyMongoClient' is expected to be of type 'com.mongodb.client.MongoClient' but was actually of type 'com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl'

Answer (score 0):

```
1) In a Tomcat installation, copy the mongo-java-driver jar file into the lib directory.

2) In context.xml of a web application, add a resource that references the MongoClientFactory class, and the connection string for the MongoDB cluster:


    <Resource name="jdbc/MyMongo"
              auth="Container"
              type="com.mongodb.MongoClient"
              closeMethod="close"
              factory="com.mongodb.client.jndi.MongoClientFactory"
              singleton="true"
              connectionString="mongodb://localhost"/>

3) In web.xml of a web application, add a reference to the above resource:

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>
        jdbc/MyMongo
    </res-ref-name>
    <res-type>
        com.mongodb.MongoClient
    </res-type>
    <res-auth>
        Container
    </res-auth>
</resource-ref>


and at last mongoClient instance will be accessible via tha JNDI 

DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyMongo");
```